# Non-looping way to assign to one column according to value of another column

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I want to fill in the missing values of one column, according to the values of another column from a different dataframe.

I am practicing some cleaning in R, and I am using the "athlete_events.csv" file from this Kaggle dataset https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results

What I want to do is replace the missing values in the Age column for each athlete, with the mean age of the sport in which that athlete competed in.

I'm still quite a beginner so there might be a few redundant bits of code.

But first I read in the file:

```
olympic_tbl = read_csv("athlete_events.csv", n_max = 500)
```

Then I create a new dataframe called "mean_sport_age" containing two columns - the Sport and mean age of competitors in that sport. I change the row label to be the name Sport, and the column names for easier indexing.

```
mean_sport_age = olympic_tbl %>% group_by(Sport) %>% summarize(mean(Age, na.rm=TRUE))
mean_sport_age = as.data.frame(mean_sport_age)
row.names(mean_sport_age) = mean_sport_age$Sport
colnames(mean_sport_age) = c("Sport","Age")
```

Then I iterate through each row of the original data  dataframe, check if the Age value is missing, and if it is missing I look up the Sport of the athlete, and then use that to look up the mean age for that Sport, to replace the missing value in the age column:

```
for (i in 1:500) {
  if (is.na(olympic_tbl[i,]$Age)){
    sport = olympic_tbl[i,]$Sport
    olympic_tbl[i,]$Age = mean_sport_age[sport,"Age"]
  }
}
```

I got the expected result I wanted - **however, is there a faster way to do this that doesn't loop through each row of the dataframe?**

Comment: You can just use `olympic_tbl$Age[is.na(olympic_tbl$Age)] = mean(olympic_tbl$Age,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @boski but that's just taking the mean (with the na values removed) of the "Age" column without taking into account the "Sport" of each individual athlete is it not? I want the age to depend on the sport that the individual played.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the sport for each individual, you can use a `dplyr` pipe like:

```
olympic_tbl %>% group_by(Sport) %>% mutate(Age=ifelse(is.na(Age),mean(Age, na.rm=TRUE),Age))
```

If the value is `na`, it will be updated by the mean of the group. Else, it will remain the same.